# Jquery .text() function behaviour

Tags: jquery

I have this html snippet:

```
<div clas="some-div">
  <span class="same-class">text 1</span>
  <span class="same-class">text 2</span>
</div>
```

I want to extract **text1** and **text2** into two different variables.

```
var allText = $('.same-class').text(); //gives text 1text2
var t1 = $('.same-class')[0].text(); //gives error
```

How does **.text()** function behave?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use [`.eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) for this purpose,

```
var t1 = $('.same-class').eq(0).text();
```

If you use bracket notation to access the elements based on its index, then that will return a plain `node` object. And that will not contain a function called `text` in its prototype.

If you still want to use bracket notation, then do,

```
var t1 = $('.same-class')[0].textContent;
```

Answer (score 3):

you could use [$.each()](https://api.jquery.com/each/) as well, like:

```
var textArr = []; //array to store text
$('.same-class').each(function(idx, val) {
    textArr.push($(this).text());
});
console.log(textArr);
```

Answer (score 2):

Description for the text(), from the [jQuery doc](http://api.jquery.com/text/):

> Description: Get the combined text contents of each element in the set of matched elements, including their descendants.

Since the jQuery object $('.same-class') contains several elements, it combines text from all the elements into a single line.

In order to get a particular element text use: the `.eq()`

```
$('.same-class').eq(0).text();
```

method